# Silverlight - Dynamic binding by visibility

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation

If I have two text boxes, one is *visible*, other one *isn't*. Both are bound to the same property.

Is there a way to bind only visible one? 
That way validation causes only one error in the **Validation Summary**?

I have a form with many fiends but also many different ways people can enter data based on their selection. So I was wondering if there is a way of maybe having a method that goes over all hidden components and **disables validation or/and unbinds it temporarily**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice short example of what you're trying to accomplish: http://blog.dotnetstep.in/2009/12/silverlight-3-enable-and-disable.html

You could use the visual tree walker in this example to walk the visual tree and remove the bindings on any framework elements who have a visibility value of collapsed:
http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/03/silverlight-visual-tree-walker.html

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I'm thinking of writing a method to loop through all invisible components and changing their binding to stop validations.

Comment: Cool, the link in my edit above should help you to walk through your visual tree to update the bindings on your invisible components.

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to mix those two together :)